# can not push function code to azure from visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, deployment, azure-functions

I am following the azure digital twin tutorial. I am using visual studio code 1.59.0 on Mac. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/tutorial-end-to-end

I like to do all from the VS code menu, skipping the azure cli.

I was able to create a function app using the deploy menu, but I can not find out how to push the .cs code to azure. All the instructions I googled have mismatching UI which does not match my own VS Code screen.

When I click on the deploy button, it only asks for the function app to push to, instead of allowing me to pick out the .cs file. When I do go thru with the push, I get a

Failed to deploy path that does not exist: /Users/xxx/workspace/digital-twins-samples/AdtSampleApp/SampleFunctionsApp/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish

I noticed some other instructions seems to indicate I must have a .zip file prepare, but that was supposed to be automatic during the deploy. So I am stuck. Can anyone help?

Comment: sudden the next Monday, I was able to push through the deployment, but only the generated function.json file was sent thru. How to deploy the *.cs files to the portal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Kudu console to drag and drop the *.cs file to the function app as explained the [article](https://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/How-to-add-edit-and-remove-files-in-your-azure-webapp-using-the-kudu-service-dashboard/)